# VBA code to create multiple workbook

Tags: vba

I need a modification in the code to save the workbooks as 1.xlsx, 2.xlsx

Current the below code doesnot allow me to save that way,,can some one help

```
Sub addbook()
Dim d As Double
d = InputBox("Enter Number of Work books to be created")
For i = 1 To d

Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "1" & i & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: so you need to create multiple workbooks by entering the number in the message box right?

Comment: i enter 10..then it should create 10 work books...but the name should be like 1.xlsx, 2. xlsx etc

Comment: the code you have runs all the commands exactly once.  you need to use a loop that exits when a certain number of iterations (repeats) have been done. it has to start repeating after you enter # of workbooks.

Comment: click on your code and press F8 repeatedly to step through the code

Comment: Sub addbook()
Dim d As Double
d = InputBox("Enter Number of Work books to be created")
For i = 1 To d

    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "1" & i & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub addbook()
Dim i As Double
j = InputBox("Enter Number of Work books to be created")
relativePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

For i = 1 To j
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=relativePath & i & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next i

End Sub
```